# Why Google Analytics show bounce rate 100% and avg time more then 1min

Tags: time, google-analytics, bounce, rate

How is possible to have on a page a 
**bounce rate = 100%**  
 
and for the same page an   
**average time on page > 1min** ?

screenshot [here](http://img.giobby.com/analytics.png)

Comment: Are you sending any non-interaction hits?

Comment: No, I'm not sending non-interaction event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the bounce rate refers to entrances (which are two in your screenshot), not to the pageviews. I.e. you have 40 pageviews that did not bounce and viewed the page 1:53 min on average, but for the 2 for whom this was the landingpage and the last (and only) page in the visit the bounce rate was by defintion 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Bounce rate is counted as the percentage of particular visitor who entered into a website and left the website without interacting with another pages of the website. 100% Bounce rate is possible for some reasons when our website content is not good, links are not working properly, not using the right keywords, page loading time, user is not getting the right information which he/she is looking for. Tips to improve the high bounce rate [visit here](http://infrawebsoft.com/blog/good-bounce-rate-for-your-website/)